# PHP the proportions of image

Tags: php

I upload the image to my site. Image has width is 498 and height is 402.
I need to make a preview image with the established maximum width of 250px and a maximum height of 250px, but the image should be 250 to 250, and must be proportional to the width of 250 pixels.

How to do it?

**EDIT**

I upload images to your server. The limit on the size I want to make 250 in width and 250 in height.
This does not mean that if I upload an image 1000h500, then it must do 250x250, which means that the width we're doing 250 pixels and the height is proportional to the first dimension is 125. In the end, I should get a picture 250x125.
Second example: I have an image 100h800. I mean it should be changed

Comment: This is not very clear. Could you please either restate what you need or give some visual examples or something else?

Comment: I second what @JMC said, specially how should the proportions be handled.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function makeThumbnail($image, $dest)
    {
        $imageType = exif_imagetype($image);

        switch ($imageType)
        {
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                $img = imagecreatefrompng($image);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $img = imagecreatefromgif($image);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Im_Exception('Bad extension');
        }

        $width  = imagesx($img);
        $height = imagesy($img);        

        if ($height > $width) 
        {   
            $ratio = 250 / $height;  
            $newHeight = 250;
            $newWidth = $width * $ratio; 
        }
        else
        {
            $ratio = 250 / $width;   
            $newWidth = 250;  
            $newHeight = $height * $ratio;   
        }

        $previewImg = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight); 

        $palsize = ImageColorsTotal($img); 
        for ($i = 0; $i < $palsize; $i++) 
        { 
            $colors = ImageColorsForIndex($img, $i);   
            ImageColorAllocate($previewImg, $colors['red'], $colors['green'], $colors['blue']);
        } 

        imagecopyresized($previewImg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

        switch ($imageType)
        {
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $ext = 'jpg';
                imagejpeg($previewImg, $dest . '.' . $ext);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $ext = 'png';
                imagesavealpha($previewImg, true);
                imagepng($previewImg, $dest . '.' . $ext, 9);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Im_Exception();
        }
        imagedestroy($previewImg);
        imagedestroy($img);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function I wrote for generating thumbnails using GD. You can pass a max width or height, or both (if zero, means unrestricted) and the thumbnail will be scaled to `$dest` (+ file extension) with proportions intact. It also works on transparent images. Any extra space left should be fully transparent; If you want a different background, modify `$img` before the `imagecopyresampled()` on it.

```
function picThumb($src, $dest, $width = 0, $height = 0, $quality = 100)
    {
    $srcType = exif_imagetype($src);

    if (!$width && !$height)
        {
        $ext = image_type_to_extension($srcType, false);
        copy($src, $dest . '.' . $ext);
        return $ext;
        }

    ini_set('memory_limit', '134217728');
    try
        {
        switch ($srcType)
            {
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $srcImg = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                $srcImg = imagecreatefrompng($src);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $srcImg = imagecreatefromgif($src);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception();
            }
        $srcWidth = imagesx($srcImg);
        $srcHeight = imagesy($srcImg);
        if (!$srcWidth || !$srcHeight)
            {
            throw new Exception();
            }

        if ($width && $height)
            {
            $ratio = min($srcWidth / $width, $srcHeight / $height);
            $areaWidth = round($width * $ratio);
            $areaHeight = round($height * $ratio);
            $areaX = round(($srcWidth - $areaWidth) / 2);
            $areaY = round(($srcHeight - $areaHeight) / 2);
            }
        else // if (!$width || !$height)
            {
            if ($width)
                {
                $height = round($width / $srcWidth * $srcHeight);
                }
            else // if ($height)
                {
                $width = round($height / $srcHeight * $srcWidth);
                }
            $areaWidth = $srcWidth;
            $areaHeight = $srcHeight;
            $areaX = 0;
            $areaY = 0;
            }

        $img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagealphablending($img, false);
        imagecopyresampled($img, $srcImg, 0, 0, $areaX, $areaY, $width, $height, $areaWidth, $areaHeight);

        switch ($srcType)
            {
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $ext = 'jpg';
                imagejpeg($img, $dest . '.' . $ext, $quality);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $ext = 'png';
                imagesavealpha($img, true);
                imagepng($img, $dest . '.' . $ext, 9);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception();
            }

        imagedestroy($srcImg);
        imagedestroy($img);
        }
    catch (Exception $e)
        {
        ini_restore('memory_limit');
        throw $e;
        }
    ini_restore('memory_limit');

    return $ext;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) class for this purposes.
Some strings of code, how to make 250x250 image and save it:

```
$img = new Imagick('/path/to/image/image.jpg'); //image.jpg - your file
$img->cropThumbnailImage(250, 250); //make thumbnail 250x250
$img->writeImage('/newptah/newfilename.jpg'); //write thumbnail to new path
$img->destroy(); //free resources
```

newfilename.jpg - would be 250x250 square without losing proportions.

Comment: If my image has 1000x100 sizes? What will I get?

Comment: check this example: http://valokuva.org/?p=8 if you have a new version of imagemagick it will keep the proportions intended.

Answer (score 0):

you can use getimagesize function. it will return an array

> $size = getimagesize($filename);
>
> $width = $size[0];
>
> $height => $size[1];

Then, since width of your image is greater than height, multiply the original width and height by 250/498

Comment: Just fyi, this way is cleaner: `list($w,$h) = getimagesize($filename);`

Comment: of course. I was just trying to focus on the main problem and keep everything else simple.